# Zehon SFTP getGileNamesInFolder works only every two days

Tags: java

I had implement a cron task who get files on a sftp server.
This task works only every two days.
I am using zehon's librairy fot create my sftp connection and get files.
On the other day I had this error :

```
com.zehon.exception.FileTransferException: org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException: Unknown message with code "Could not determine the type of file "sftp://____:***@ftp.___.org/".".
    at com.zehon.FileTransferClient.getFileNamesInFolder(FileTransferClient.java:858)
    at com.zehon.sftp.SFTPClient.getFileNamesInFolder(SFTPClient.java:668)
    at org.___.si.application.module.imports.ImportService.importer(ImportService.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:31)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:185)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:103)
    at org._____.si.application.module.imports.ImportService_$$_javassist_440.importer(ImportService_$$_javassist_440.java)
    at org._____.si.application.module.prestation.demande.tachePeriodique.ImportTache.execute(ImportTache.java:45)
    at org.____.si.application.util.batch.GestionnaireDeTache$1$1.process(GestionnaireDeTache.java:104)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.ContextualHttpServletRequest.run(ContextualHttpServletRequest.java:53)
    at org._____.si.application.util.batch.GestionnaireDeTache$1.run(GestionnaireDeTache.java:106)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException: Unknown message with code "Could not determine the type of file "sftp://_____:***@ftp._____.org/".".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.sftp.SftpFileObject.refresh(SftpFileObject.java:84)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.AbstractFileSystem.resolveFile(AbstractFileSystem.java:366)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.AbstractFileSystem.resolveFile(AbstractFileSystem.java:314)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:86)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:66)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:692)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:620)
    at com.zehon.FileTransferClient.getFileObject(FileTransferClient.java:741)
    at com.zehon.FileTransferClient.getFileNamesInFolder(FileTransferClient.java:848)
    ... 23 more
```